# Migrating from tomcat 8 to jetty server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, jetty

I have java based application running on tomcat 8 server. Lately i had some problems with the tomcat so i decided to change it with jetty server.My problem seams to be with the @Autowire annotation. Here are my changes and my console.

i have deleted dependencies and plugins for the tomcat and added some for jetty that i found online.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>7.6.8.v20121106</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.7.v20150116</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-jstl</artifactId>
        <version>9.2.7.v20150116</version>
    </dependency>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
         <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>9.2.8.v20150217</version>
    </plugin>
```

this is my console error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private
>   com.snt.hr.service.attendances.CheckInService
>   com.snt.hr.tasks.AttendanceSyncTask.checkInService;

Answer (score 0):

Right now your question does not contain enough information to render a proper answer.

But your question does hint at a few problems.

You must use the same version of Jetty everywhere, for all of your dependencies and plugins.

- Jetty 7 is EOL (End of Life)
- Jetty 9.2 is EOL (End of Life)

Use something current, stable, and supported.

https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/what-jetty-version.html

If you use current and up to date 3rd party libraries then it's important to use at least Jetty 9.4.9 or newer (as various 3rd party libraries have started to adopt the JSR-238 Multi-Release JAR Archive - https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238, and Jetty support for such JAR archives only exists in Jetty 9.4.x)

Note that once you upgrade Jetty, your spring dependencies (which you haven't listed in your question) will likely also require being upgraded, as older versions of Spring do not work with newer versions of Jetty, for various technical reasons, some Jetty's doing, some Java's doing, some Spring's bad assumptions.

Your chosen list of Jetty dependencies seems short.  It's a valid list, and will help you get started as most of the more important dependencies will be pulled in from `jetty-annotations`, but that bare bones setup is unusual.

I see you are pulling in JSP.  JSP is a special delicate flower of a technology and requires a fair bit of setup to function properly.

See: https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-jsp